# "Safari can't connect to the Server" when using Google Calendar API

Tags: python, json, google-calendar-api

So I'm using the Google Calendar API and I'm able to login, but as soon as I open the app, it can't load up the page.

This is my code

```
from pprint import pprint
import datetime
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "client_secret.json"
API_NAME = "calendar"
API_VERSION = "v3"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]


creds = None
if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=creds)
```

Comment: Can you explain what your workflow is? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I was expecting for google calendar to open when I run my code

Comment: That's not what this code does, this simply authorises your application to make calls to the Caldendar API. What is your end goal?

Comment: My end goal is to creating a scheduling based web app where I can have a calendar display on my app and be able to add and adjust availability times

Comment: So if this code is supposed to authorize my application, do you know why it's unable to authorize my account?

Comment: What does the code do when run? How are you running it? Have you followed all the steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python)?

Comment: Yes, I actually just tried that code out earlier and I am able to log in with my gmail, but when it allow the app to access my google account, it takes me to the error page. I am running it through visual studio code

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to authorize this using Chrome? @MattNguyen

Comment: It doesn't work when I use chrome either